# Delphi Application using COMMIT and ROLLBACK for Multiple SQL Updates

Tags: sql-server-2005, delphi, sql-server-2000

Is it possible to use the SQL BEGIN TRANSACTION, COMMIT TRANSACTION, ROLLBACK TRANSACTION when embedding SQL Queries into an application with mutiple calls to the SQL for Table Updates.  For example I have the following code:

```
Q.SQL.ADD(<UPDATE A RECORD>);
Q.ExecSQL;

Q.Close;
Q.SQL.Clear;
Q.SQL.ADD(<Select Some Data>);
Q.Open;
```

Set Some Variables

```
Q.Close;
Q.SQL.Clear;
Q.SQL.ADD(<UPDATE A RECORD>);
Q.ExecSQL;
```

What I would like to do is if the second update fails I want to roll back the first transaction.

If I set a unique notation for the BEGIN, COMMIT, ROLLBACK so as to specify what is being committed or rolled back, is it feasible.

i.e. before the first Update specify BEGIN TRANSACTION_A
then after the last update specify COMMIT TRANSACTION_A

I hope that makes sense.  If I was doing this in a SQL Stored Procedure then I would be able to specify this at the start and end of the procedure, but I have had to break the code down into manageable chunks due to process blocks and deadlocks on a heavy loaded SQL Server.

Comment: Hi, Matt!  Welcome to StackOverflow.  I edited your post to highlight the code.  It needs a special style so it will be formatted properly.  If you need to ask another question with a code sample in it, highlight the code when you're done and hit the button with all the 1s and 0s. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to use StartTransaction, Commit and Rollback on the Connection?

e.g.

```
Q.Connection.StartTransaction
try
    Q.SQL.ADD(); 
    Q.ExecSQL;

    Q.Close; 
    Q.SQL.Clear; 
    Q.SQL.ADD(); 
    Q.Open;

    ...


    Q.Close; 
    Q.SQL.Clear; 
    Q.SQL.ADD(); 
    Q.ExecSQL;
    Q.Connection.Commit;
except
    Q.Connection.Rollback;
end;
```

Comment: Ah that is what I am looking for, so as I am using Delphi 5, and TADOConnection I guess I will need to use:

Q.Connection.BeginTrans;
Q.Connection.CommitTrans;
Q.Connection.RollbackTrans;

Thanks

Comment: I think there's a logical problem in this solution. When the sql statement in the 3rd line fails it raises an exception and you're left with a pending transaction. To avoid this you will have to move the try statement upwards and make it the 2nd line